# How to load json data in dhtmlx grid using Codeigniter 3 HMVC?

Tags: json, codeigniter, dhtmlx

I am pulling a json data from my controller but I don't know how can I render those data in my grid.

Here's my sample code:

**VIEW**

```
<script type="text/javascript">

    var myGrid;

    function loadProjects() {
        myGrid = new dhtmlXGridObject('project-list');
        myGrid.setHeader("ID, Contract ID, Client ID, Client, Assigned Officer, Start Date, End Date, Status"); 
        myGrid.init();
        myGrid.load("<?php echo site_url('projects/projects/load_project_list'); ?>");
    }

    $(window).on('load', function() {
        loadProjects();
    });

</script>
```

**CONTROLLER**

```
public function load_project_list() {

    header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *');
    header("Content-Type: application/json");
    $json = array();
    $this->load->model('projects/Projects_model');
    $projects = $this->Projects_model->get_projects();
    $json['data'] = $projects;
    echo json_encode($json);;

}
```

**MODELS**

```
public function get_projects() {
        $list = $this->db->get('tr_projects');
        return ($list) ? $list->result() : array();
    }
```

Sample JSON:

```
{"data":[{"id":"1","contract_id":"542454","client_id":"5641454","client":"Terada","officer":"Miki","start_date"
:"2016-03-02","end_date":"2016-03-02","status":"1"},{"id":"2","contract_id":"423434","client_id":"6534544"
,"client":"Meme","officer":"Miki","start_date":"2016-03-02","end_date":"2016-03-02","status":"1"}]
}
```

I can get the json value but it doesn't shows in the table. Is there a JSON format that I need to do?

Comment: http://docs.dhtmlx.com/grid__json_configuration.html looks like the required format is a bit different than yours - just fit it in and it should work

Comment: By default the grid expects an xml file, if you're using json in the load call send as a 2nd parameter "json".
myGrid.load("<?php echo site_url('projects/projects/load_project_list'); ?>", "json");>
Also as sintakonte stated your json format is wrong